# how to Views call images of each node? I saw that is not in SQL of the view

Tags: views, media, database

I have a View that shows the first image of each node (so, a common View). I saw the SQL of this view, and I saw that the image is not called inside this SQL, so, what's the way that Views call images of each node?

Comment: I must say that the field of each image is an CCK image field.

Comment: I want to know this regarding Drupal 6. thanks for all for descriptions related Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views for Drupal 7 uses entity_load() to display Field API fields (to load the entity for each row and get the field data).
It is not pulled through SQL, which is why you don't see it (the field table gets added only once you filter by a field, etc).

This is because Field API expects to receive a full entity when rendering a field. Views tried to simulate an entity (before alpha1 was released), but that failed miserably (broken formatters, translation fallback...). Hence the current approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed description. do you know how this happen in Drupal 6?

Comment: For Drupal 6 the CCK integration is provided by the CCK module itself. And there a fake $node object is constructed out of values fetched from the database, and then passed along to content_format().

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your view is configured to show nodes instead of fields.

When a view is showing nodes (either as teaser or full), the view only uses SQL to get which nodes to show. Then it calls `node_load()` and `node_view()` before outputting. `node_view()` will output a node just like you were looking at it regularly and this is where the image is being pulled in, not in views itself (hence why there is no SQL to get the image).

When a view is showing fields, it grabs all the fields data using SQL instead of `node_load()` and displays that data using it's own templates instead of `node_view()`.

Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Hello. my view is configured to show fileds. I must say that the fields are CCK image field.

Comment: Then I'm way off base. Sounds like kalabro is on the right track though

Answer (score 0):

I just tested for Drupal 7 and it actually happens even if you use mode "Fields".
As I can see from source of Views 3.0-rc1, Views uses special function [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) for displaying field and don't need to join on any tables. It allows to use cached data for fields, as I think.
If you turn on filter or sorting by image field, then JOIN will appears.

Comment: Hi kalabro, thanks for your detailed description. do you know how this happen in Drupal 6? I saw that the field_view_field() is not in Drupal 6.